# Creating a scrolling grid of different width cells

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to c# and WinPhone7 development and need a bit of guidance if someone could be so kind, so please excuse my ignorance.

The issue I have is I need to create a Grid view for a TV Guide where you have a vertical list of channel logos on the left that scrolls up and down, and to its right we have a horizontally and vertically scrolling grid. Horizontal scrolling doesnt move the channel logos which is fixed on screen, but vertically scrolling grid also scrolls the logos as you would expect.

Should I continue to attempt to do this using XAML and Silverlight or should I just do it via XNA?

I ask because I have tried several different methods via Silverlight to get over to the two main problems I have:

**Performance**

As I receive the data from our API using ASync requests I create a background worker thread which parses the JSON and creates programme cells on the grid 'canvas' view using Dispatch.Invoke. As this happens there is no gradual feedback, the whole thing waits until everything is done and then suddenly the grid appears. I would like the cells to appear on a channel by channel basis or on a cell-by-cell basis without blocking the UI so scrolling still works nicely but this doesnt seem to happen.

I am having issues as any sort of work using UIElements is done on the UI thread which on WinPhone7 is the main thread (I believe), this includes parsing XAML or creating/modiyfing UIElements even if they arent added to anything on-screen or visible. This means I cannot improve things by pre-creating or re-using elements.

I have tried doing as much as possible in a worker thread and just the tiny bit of UI work being dispatched to the UI thread to minimise the blocking, and it doesnt seem to help.

**Memory**

Clearly I cannot create 'programme cells' for each tv programme event for potentially hundreds (we support more than 650 channels) for 7 days as the phone would run out of memory very quickly; so I would like to create a virtual grid where cells are created and loaded into the canvas view only for the viewport being currently seen.

I have two problems with this:

1. the UI blocking of doing any UI work stops any scrolling as above so creating new cells in the background that are to be scrolled into view cant happen without blocking the UI
2. there are no scroll events being sent by the scroll view, I have experimented with binding to the scrollbars in the scrollview to get offset values but this doesnt work very well as it just updates in fits and starts so if you do lots of scrolling, nothing gets sent until there is a pause or OnIdle I guess.

Is it me messing up and should I therefore persevere, or I am doing something that cant be done and I should try a different tact like doing it via XNA?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: A bit more information and some sample code**

I have a Programme class that contains things like start time and title, a Channel class that has name and logo etc but also an array of programmes.

When I retrieve my API data, I create a channel object and add it to an array of channels, then I add the programmes to the channels Programmes array. Once all the programmes for a channel have been added to the array I post it to an ChannelProgrammesComplete event listener for the UI to be updated.

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Canvas x:Name="ProgGrid" 
                    Height="55" Width="393" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>


public void ChannelProgrammesComplete( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  bw.DoWork += ( doWorkSender, args ) =>
  {
    Dispatch( (Channel)sender );
  };
  bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Dispatch( BackgroundWorker bw, object param )
{
  Channel channel = (Channel)param;

  int progCount = 0;
  foreach( Programme programme in channel.Programmes )
  {
    double left = ( ( programme.StartSecsFromToday / 60 ) * PixelsPerMinute );  // turn it into seconds

    if( progCount == 0 && left < 0 )
    {
      // If first prog starts before 6am, shrink the cell so it starts at the 6am start point
      programme.UIWidth = ( ( programme.Duration - ( ( programme.StartSecsFromToday / 60 ) * -1 ) ) * PixelsPerMinute ) - _cellPadding;
      left = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      programme.UIWidth = ( programme.Duration * PixelsPerMinute ) - _cellPadding;  // Multiply by zoom level which is 3 for now, and take off the amount we use for right margin grid separator
    }
    Debug.Assert( programme.UIWidth > 0 );

    programme.UITop = channel.SortIndex * ( _rowHeight + _cellPadding );
    programme.UILeft = left;
    programme.UIHeight = _rowHeight;

    object[] invokeArgs = new object[ 1 ];
    invokeArgs[ 0 ] = programme;

    // Do as much work as possible in the thread before dispatching to the UI thread for the simple UI work
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new InvokeProgrammeCellDelegate( AddProgrammeCellDelegate ), invokeArgs );
  }
}


public delegate void InvokeProgrammeCellDelegate( Programme prog );
public void AddProgrammeCellDelegate( Programme prog )
{
  Rectangle progCell = new Rectangle();
  progCell.Fill = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb( 0xFF, (byte)( 0x13 ), (byte)( 0x45 ), (byte)( 0x70 ) ) );
  progCell.Height = prog.UIHeight;
  progCell.Width = prog.UIWidth;

  progCell.SetValue( Canvas.TopProperty, prog.UITop );
  progCell.SetValue( Canvas.LeftProperty, prog.UILeft );

  ProgGrid.Children.Add( progCell );
  ProgGrid.Width = Math.Max( ProgGrid.Width, prog.UIWidth + prog.UILeft );
}
```

Comment: This answer is _really_ hard, especially if you don't provide us with the problematic code. Despite that it sounds like you should be able to do it without XNA, as long as you get rid of that ugly panel thing (hint: the name starts wit a 'C') which will totally destroy your performance as soon as you do anything more complex with it than displaying static items at the upper left corner ;)

Comment: Loading Data when the User Scrolls to the End of a List tutorial: http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Comment: @Tobias I have added a bit of code now; this sample removes all the stackpanels I was using (which is the only way I can think of to create a vertically scrolling channel logo panel and a separate grid panel that scrolls both horizontally and vertically), absolutely no difference in speed occurred. If I scroll around whilst the data is being processed, it spluts and stops and then suddenly the whole grid will appear ... no gradual rendering and no smooth UI happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using a large `Canvas` should be only the last resort - in most cases combinations of `Grid` or `StackPanel` (sometimes within other `StackPanel`s) and items with a `Margin` will be much faster (they will be slightly more difficult to handle though).

To keep the app responsive you could

1. Only load small chunks of data at once (like, for example, two pages. This will greatly decrease the amount of data being rendered simultaneously). Then you can load the next chunk either immediately or when the user scrolls at the end of the list.
2. Speed down the result processing. If you wait 100ms after inserting each item (or 1 second after each channel, if you want to have the channel loaded at once), the impact on responsiveness should be almost gone while having no *too* large impact on loading time. The times mentioned are only estimates, if they are too large/small feel free to adjust them according too your needs to provide a smooth user experience.

Comment: Thanks. I was given to understanding that stacking loads of elements would actually be worse performance wise so was informed that canvas would be better. Using a grid of elements stacked up, would be tricky to do because drawing a cell for a 7pm programme on multiple rows will be difficult to line up if there are many programmes before it on one row but not another (I did first try this and lots of issues so went to canvas as it was much more precise on positioning). I will try delaying the processing; again I had tried that with one of my other attempts but will try again.

Comment: Adding a small Thread.Sleep worked and gave the ui some idle time to update things. Hopefully I will get more scroll property events so I can virtualise it. Thanks.